# VS Code is now asking if I want to run the file normally or to run it in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The thing is that, it never asked me this before, is there a way to fix this? Because clicking 2 times the start button to run the program is a little annoying. Thanks!

Comment: Which VS Code extensions did you use?
Is the "Code Runner" extension used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code, the green run button provided by the "Python" extension is to execute the command "`Run Python File in Terminal`". It only requires us to click once to run python files in the Terminal of VS Code:

[image]

If you also use other extensions, such as: "Code Runner", the run button ("Run Code") provided by it defaults to output results in "OUTPUT". In the previous use, this button will cover the green button provided by the "python" extension, but now that they are integrated, we can choose the execution method.

You could use F5 to debug the code or try to close the "Code Runner" extension. (Click "`Enable`" to restore the use of the extension.)

Comment: thanks to Jill Cheng now everything works! Sorry for answering so late! I thought I already answered